# Using google drive SDK to download file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api

I have followed this example:

```
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

......
......


/// <summary>
        /// Download a file and return a string with its content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="authenticator">
        /// Authenticator responsible for creating authorized web requests.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="file">Drive File instance.</param>
        /// <returns>File's content if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
        private System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(IAuthenticator authenticator, Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                        new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
                    authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        return response.GetResponseStream();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                return null;
            }
        }
```

but the namespace using `Google.Apis.Authentication` cannot be found anyware
so the input parameter `IAuthenticator authenticator` cannot be resolved.

I have installed from Nuget both the

> Google APIs Client Library
>
> Google.api.drive.v2 Client Library

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I had the same problem that you have described and the API documentation does not give enough information on what the IAuthenticator is. As rajanmhr47 said, it's not supported anymore and is going to be removed.

The solution is as follows:

Assuming you have a `DriveService` instance variable that you used to authenticate to the Google Drive API servers, you can use it like so to download a file that you have permission to:

Note: These methods do not implement any error checking.

Async version:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadFile(DriveService driveService, string fileId)
{
    var file = await driveService.Files.Get(fileId).ExecuteAsync();
    return await driveService.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(file.DownloadUrl);
}
```

Synchronous version:

```
public static byte[] DownloadFile(DriveService driveService, string fileId)
{
    var file = driveService.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
    return driveService.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(file.DownloadUrl).Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Authentication/IAuthenticator.cs?r=e6585033994bfb3a24d4c140db834cb14b9738b2) it is mentioned that IAuthenticator is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta. Consider using UserCredential or ServiceAccountCredential from the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package which supports .NET 4, .NET for Windows, Store apps, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 and Portable Class Libraries as well